# Print only the lines that contain three sequential consecutive numbers

Tags: regex, awk, sed, command-line, grep

I'm filtering a text file with numbers and names I want to print only the lines that contain sets of three sequential consecutive digits. The input list:

```
123 321 567 765 124 5689 12345.
```

The output should contain:

```
123 321 567 765 12345
```

I have tried this command

```
awk ' {split ("", N) # delete array N 
L = 1 # initialize boolean L to TRUE
for (i=1; i<=length($1); i++){ # for each digit
    P = substr($1, i, 1) 
    if (N[P-1] || N[P+1]){ # if contiguous digit exists, 
        L = 0 break # set L to FALSE; and quit the for loop 
    } N[P] = 1 } } L ' file
```

but it is not working as intended.

I like any `sed` or grep or `awk` command to work with.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you tell us what you've tried so far?

Comment: I want any sed or grep or awk command to work with.

Answer (score 2):

This is the basic regex for 3 sequential (ascending or descending) numbers.

`(?:012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789)|(?:987|876|765|654|543|432|321|210)`

https://regex101.com/r/hd5PzR/1

You can decorate it with `\d*(?:(?:012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789)|(?:987|876|765|654|543|432|321|210))\d*`
if needed.

https://regex101.com/r/hd5PzR/2

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for help on homework or are you trying to solve a problem? If the latter is the case, using an algorithmic approach when there are so few combinations is like using a chain saw to cut butter. Consider the following script:

```
mystring="012 123 234 567 678 789"
revstring=$(echo $mystring|rev)
checkstring="$mystring $revstring"

for checkno in $(echo $checkstring);
do
        grep $checkno numbers
done
```

Note that this will get you duplicate output for lines containing more than one sequence, but just run that through |sort -u to eliminate them.

Comment: Dear Kyle Banerjee please I am using kali linux i need sed or awk or grep command i don't know how to yous your above command.

Comment: It's a shell script. I don't know which shells it works for.

Comment: That was for bash